# How to get Twain DataSource file (*.ds) on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, datasource, twain

My goal is make same code works on Win7_64 and Linux(Centos 7_64) for scanner(using TWAIN). I am coding on C++ Qt. My programm works fine on Win7_64, but when I tried to launch it on Linux; I found that DataSource Manager couldn't find DataSource. Therefore, I tried to figure out how to get that DataSource. I didn't find any useful information about it; I only know that on Linux DataSource looks like *.ds file, and my question is how to get it? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Twain drivers are mostly an abstract idea. If there are any out there, they're very few and come with expensive equipment. So, unfortunately, forget about Twain on Linux. You need to use Sane.

Of course you could insert a Twain adapter layer between Sane and your application. At least one such layer exists, but it's for OS X: [Twain Sane](http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/). It shouldn't be terribly hard to adapt it for linux, the source is available.